# Chakra UI - Checkbox Group

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I am using Chakra UI with React Typescript and implementing a checkbox group
The default values are controlled by an outside state that is passed down as a prop.

The problem is that the CheckboxGroup doesn't accept the default values from outside source

The code is as follows:

```
import React, {FC, useCallback, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { CheckboxGroup, Checkbox, VStack } from "@chakra-ui/react";

interface IGroupCheckbox {
    values: StringOrNumber[],
    labels: StringOrNumber[],
    activeValues: StringOrNumber[]
    onChange: (value:StringOrNumber[])=> void

}
const GroupCheckbox:FC<IGroupCheckbox> = ({
    values,
    labels,
    activeValues,
    onChange
}) => {
    const [currActiveValues, setCurrActiveValues] = useState<StringOrNumber[]>();
    const handleChange = useCallback((value:StringOrNumber[]) => {
        if(value?.length === 0) {
            alert('you must have at least one supported language');
            return;
        }
        onChange(value);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(activeValues) {
            setCurrActiveValues(['en'])
        }
    },[activeValues])

    return (
        <CheckboxGroup 
            onChange={handleChange}
            defaultValue={currActiveValues}
        >
            <VStack>
                {values && labels && values.map((item:StringOrNumber, index:number)=>
                    {
                        return (
                            <Checkbox 
                                key={item} 
                                value={item}
                            >
                                {labels[index]}
                            </Checkbox>
                        )
                    }
                )}
            </VStack>
        </CheckboxGroup>
    )
}

export default GroupCheckbox
```

When I change the defaultValue parameter, instead of the state managed, to be `defaultValue={['en']}` it works fine, but any other input for this prop doesn't work.
I checked and triple checked that the values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, passing a `defaultValue` prop "from an outside source" actually does work. I guess that in your code, only `['en']` works correctly because you explicitly use `setCurrActiveValues(['en'])` instead of `setCurrActiveValues(activeValues)`.

The `defaultValue` prop will only be considered on the **initial render** of the component; changing the defaultValue prop afterwards will be **ignored**. **Solution:** make it a controlled component, by using the `value` prop instead of `defaultValue`.

Note that unless you pass a parameter to `useState()`, you will default the state variable to `undefined` on that initial render.

Side note: You also don't need a separate state variable `currActiveValues`. Instead, you can simply use `activeValues` directly.

```js
const GroupCheckbox = ({ values, labels, activeValues, onChange }: IGroupCheckbox) => {
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (value: StringOrNumber[]) => {
      if (value?.length === 0) {
        alert("you must have at least one supported language")
        return
      }
      onChange(value)
    },
    [onChange]
  )

  return (
    <CheckboxGroup onChange={handleChange} value={activeValues}>
      <VStack>
        {labels && values?.map((item: StringOrNumber, index: number) => (
          <Checkbox key={item} value={item}>
            {labels[index]}
          </Checkbox>
        ))}
      </VStack>
    </CheckboxGroup>
  )
}
```